# jax-rs web service giving 404 when using embedded jetty

Tags: java, reflection, jax-rs, jetty

This has been bugging me for the past 2 days now.My problem is that  i have developed a jax-rs web service using embedded jetty and this works completely fine as a standalone project.The problem arises when i try to call the main method that starts the jetty server via reflection from another code. I have cross checked that there are no class-loader issues (apparently as no error is being thrown) but the path at which i access my web service returns 404,no errors are thrown.I can see from the logs that the server is starting just fine  but the rest endpoint is not being hit or resolved or whatever is the reason for 404.Also note that the dependent jars for that project as well as the class containing the main method are being loaded via a url classloader created from the urls of the source files and jars. Desperately need help

Code that starts jetty server

public void startJettyServer() {

```
    try {
        /* code to enable logging in jetty */
        StdErrLog logger = new StdErrLog();
        logger.setLevel(1);
        Log.setLog(logger);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        /*
         * code to enable startup listeners StartupListener sup=new
         * StartupListener(); context.addEventListener(sup);
         */

        Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
        jettyServer.setHandler(context);
        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);


        //jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                //org.demonking.JettyServiceApp.class.getCanonicalName());
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
         "org.demonking");

        System.out.println("i am here");
        jettyServer.start();
        // jettyServer.join();
        // jettyServer.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        // jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}
```

code that calls this method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try 
        {
            AppServer appServer = new AppServer();
            appServer.startJettyServer();

            System.out.println("exiting main");
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("in exception in app class");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Code that calls the main method via reflection

```
List<URL> urlsR = new ArrayList<URL>();
//location of source files
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\DemonKing\\Documents\\eclipseprojects\\JettyDemo\\bin\\");
            // convert the file to URL format
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            urlsR.add(url);
//location of dependent jars
            File file2 = new File("F:\\JettyJarsComplete");
            for (File child : file2.listFiles()) {
                File resFile = new File(file2 + "\\" + child.getName());
                System.out.println(resFile);
                URL url2 = resFile.toURI().toURL();
                urlsR.add(url2);
            }

            URL[] urls = urlsR.toArray(new URL[urlsR.size()]);

            // load this folder into Class loader
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("org.demonking.App");
            Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
            m.invoke(null, (Object) null);
```

Comment: Could you put some code? It is hard to say anything right now

Comment: @RafałSokalski edited my post

Comment: Can somenone atleast comment on whether what i amtrying to achieve is achievable or not? and if it is please point me in the direction